# Jenkins: Control workspace location in perforce

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I'm trying to write a Jenkins job for compiling on several platforms. For this, I need the client to be created not in the default location (C:\Jenkins\workspace\MY_JOB) but on a network location (\somecomputer\somewhere.)

I tried to unclick "Let Jenkins Create Workspace" and create the workspace myself. However, it fails. I see in the log:

```
"C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe" workspace -o MY_JOB-230942967
```

I can't figure out what this number is, and why perforce plugin adds it there, and what I may do about it.

Comment: Setting aside all of the general warnings about using P4 workspaces that are on shared network volumes, what is failing?   The log line you've given is just Jenkins attempting to do what you requested, create a new workspace with a unique identifier.   The -# is a unique ID intended to keep workspaces from colliding by making sure each unique node has its own workspace (per project).

Comment: The problem is that I had created a p4 workspace named MY_JOB, and expected that "Let Jenkins Create Workspace" would use it. However, it uses MY_JOB-230942967. I can rename the workspace, but I don't if the aforementioned number will change tomorrow - I don't control it and I don't know what it means.

Comment: If you have unclicked the Create Workspace, then the configuration probably has the node information stuck in it.   In your Jenkins configuration, what is the Workspace set to when you have `Let Jenkins Create Workspace` turned off?   I think I can guide you through getting this working.

Answer (score 9):

Open the "Advanced" settings section on the Source Code Management bit of the job configuration, and then look for

Client name format for slaves

it's, by default, ${basename}-${hash}. Delete the hash part and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problems as the OP and this sorted it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure the perforce workspace name and paths correctly for each project you want to build using jenkins. Prior to that I would suggest setting up a perforce workspace (i.e. client) for this mapping using `p4` or `p4v`.

1. Go to Jenkins webpage, and select the project you want to change
2. Select Configure in the left pane.
3. Under source code management make sure `Perforce` is selected, and `P4PORT`, `username` and `password` are valid as well.
4. For `Workspace (client)`, enter a valid workspace name aka the client name you pass to the `p4 client` command. Jenkins would create one for you if one such does not already exist if you check `Let Jenkins Create Workspace`
5. Select `View Map` for the `Client View Type`.
6. Enter the correct perforce mapping like you would specify in your `p4 client`. For example to map the depot location `//depot/branch1` to some path `Z:\workspace1\somedir\branch1` in your client called `myclient1` whose Client root is set at `Z:\workspace1`, you would need to add the following line:

   ```
   //depot/branch1/... //myclient1/somedir/branch1
   ```

Comment: That's basically what I did, but the client is not created/searched with the name I wanted, but with a random number added to it.